# On differentiating an integral with respect to a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and let

$$
Q = \int \! g(\mathbf{x})f(\mathbf{x})   \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
$$

What is the result of the following differentiation?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial g}Q = \frac{\partial}{\partial g} \int \! g(\mathbf{x})f(\mathbf{x})   \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
$$

I think that the answer is just $\int \! f(\mathbf{x})   \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$  **[EDIT: I'm Wrong!]**, but I am afraid that there's something tricky around. 
Besides, what if I have to find $ \partial Q/\partial g$ but the integral is defined over a region of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is everything as before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\partial /\partial g$ mean? For example, let $g(x,y)=x^2+\sin(x^2+y)$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, it just means the derivative of $Q$ with respect to the **function** $g$. I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $f$.  Or more correctly $h \mapsto \int f(x)h(x) dx $.  Its a linear map, and the derivative of a linear map is itself.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen! Very enlightening! Could you help me about the other question? What about the case where the integral if over a region $\Omega$?

Comment: Its the same.  Remember $F(f+h) = F(f) + F'(f)(h) + o(|h|)$.  Of course, you have to define what you mean by $|h|$ when the space is infinite dimensional (e.g. as in the case of the space of functions on $\Omega$).